# Using chi square test to determine representativeness of sample drawn from known population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, chi-squared-test, survey-sampling

I am trying something out of my comfort zone and would appreciate any help provided!

I have used census data to identify the frequency of age brackets in my town. I then sampled about a thousand residents on their age, and I want to determine how well my survey did in terms of drawing a representative sample.

For my town, imagine the data showed:

| Bracket | Survey | Census |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-14 | 123 | 1560 |
| 15-24 | 234 | 2670 |
| 25-34 | 345 | 3780 |

I have conducted a chi square test on the data using R and found that a significant difference, meaning my sample was not perfectly representative (and/or overpowered).

Still, I want to quantify "representativeness" in some way. Am I on target with my approach? Is there an established metric I should consider instead?

Thanks

Comment: Did you sample the ages at the time of the census or right now? We have this nasty habit of getting older.

Comment: Hah! Good question. The census data is circa 2019, so yes it is a bit outdated. I'm OK with setting that aside for now, my question is more about how to quantify representativeness of a sample than about how to ensure perfectly valid inference from this one example.

Comment: The right way to quantify representativeness is in the context of your survey's needs.  What would be a "nonrepresentative" result for your survey analysis?  How far off the true proportions would it have to be in order to concern you?  In what fashion?  For instance, if it's crucial that your survey include children, you might focus on reproducing the proportion of children (to within expected sampling error, of course) and not worry much about getting too many or two few seniors.  That's why using a universal, one-size-fits-all measure might not be a good idea.

Comment: A big part of my question hits on the weirdness of using a statistical test to determine representativeness, as by doing so I am predicting the null hypothesis: I want any test of difference between sample and population to be null so I can conclude they are not different. But that is self-serving, I am not going to sample fewer people to nerf my statistical power so I can conclude a null effect. So what is a more appropriate test where I am not predicting the null?

Comment: Please show the table for your chi-squared test, along with the P-value of the test.

Comment: I cannot follow what you might mean by "predicting the null hypothesis."